# Loop through array and creating new arrays based on object properties

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, sorting

I have an array filled with mixed user Inventory objects.
the objects have an object.name attribute.
when I iterate through the array it will already be sorted by name.
if we looked at obj.name in the array it would have this structure
[ball,ball,monkey,monkey,sausage]

1. I would like to loop through the array.
2. get all elements with common name attribute and create a new array out of those
   elements.

any suggestions there? bonus points if we can name the array the object.name attribute.
I am using Kotlin.

Here is the code/thoughts I have to start,
any other suggestions are appreciated if this is not doable

```
private fun sortElements(){
        val temp = userstuff[0].name //but what if they only have 1 of these names.. doesnt work
        userstuff.forEach { element ->
            if(temp == element.name)
             we have another item with same name put in appropriate array
             else{
                  new array 
                  loop
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your use case correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```kotlin
private fun sortElements(input: List<Stuff>) = input.groupBy { it.name }
```

The idea here is that you take each element and put it into a `Map` where the key is the `name` value and the values are a `List` of your objects.

To give an example here, let's say I have a `data class` called `Stuff`:

```kotlin
data class Stuff(
    val name: String,
    val otherField: Int,
)
```

and test data that looks like this:

```kotlin
val userStuff = listOf(
    Stuff("ball", 242),
    Stuff("ball", 11),
    Stuff("monkey", 848),
    Stuff("monkey", 455),
    Stuff("sausage", 836),
)
```

Calling the function above would give a result like this (this would be a `Map<String, Stuff>`, I just printed it out so you can see what's in there):

```
{
    ball=[
        Stuff(name=ball, otherField=242),
        Stuff(name=ball, otherField=11)
    ],
    monkey=[
        Stuff(name=monkey, otherField=848),
        Stuff(name=monkey, otherField=455)
    ],
    sausage=[
        Stuff(name=sausage, otherField=836)
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Kotlin has so many interesting abilities. Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Kotlin's a blast in part because of cool built-in functions like these.